# How do I implement a swipe to turn page animation in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css-animations

There are tons of jquery page turning animation scripts, but I keep hearing that I should try to avoid jquery when building a mobile app. So so far I've done without it.

Is there a way that AngularJS can accomplish a page-flip on swipe with a matching animation? Will I need to use jquery to accomplish this without having to write a ton of code?

Thanks!

Comment: From what I've seen with ng-animate from videos on youtube you can setup a couple of CSS classes then use ng-animate to switch the classes appropriately.  I haven't given this a go myself for anything going from one view to another, but have used it for animating some navigation arrow. Check out some details here:http://www.nganimate.org/ assuming the animation can be done with CSS transitions I think this would work.

Comment: I've seen ng-animate and played with it a bit, I guess I'm not advanced enough in css to figure out how to do this well in CSS. This is the best I've found so far: http://motyar.blogspot.com/2010/03/page-curl-fold-or-peel-effect-with-pure.html

Answer (score 2):

TurnJs is something that I personally have used and have had no problems with. It can be found  [here](http://www.turnjs.com). Is this what you are looking for? If not search CSS page flip animation and there are other alternatives.

Comment: Yep, I've seen this, but I'm always concerned about using outside JS scripts that aren't part of the angular family. Are you using this within AnguarJS?

Comment: Sorry, no. I just used it for a mobile website -- didn't really have to worry about using outside scripts.

Comment: Check this out? : http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/05/07/experimental-page-layout-inspired-by-flipboard/